# Book title on even pages, chapter on odd pages

Tags: books, scrlayer-scrpage

I would like the title of my book (or any other text) to appear on even pages, and the chapter on odd pages.
The default setting seems to be chapters on even, section on odd pages (please see the MWE attached).

The following code seems to work for the title:

```
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
%  \markboth{\MakeTextUppercase{\ \ \ \ Essays in xx}}{}%
%}
```

but I don't know how to make the chapter (instead of the section) appear on the odd pages.

```
\documentclass[DIV12, a4paper, 12pt, listof=totocnumbered, bibliography=totoc]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{float, afterpage, rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, epstopdf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb, moreverb, relsize}
\usepackage{eurosym, calc, chngcntr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf}, skip=5pt]{caption}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace,geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=3,table-align-text-post=false} 
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\addtolength{\footskip}{-0.5cm} %Seitenzahl um 0.5cm höher setzen
\geometry{a4paper, top=30mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=30mm,headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\newcolumntype{L}{D{.}{.}{2,2}}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\newcommand*{\SuperScriptSameStyle}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \mathchoice
        {{}^{\displaystyle #1}}%
        {{}^{\textstyle #1}}%
        {{}^{\scriptstyle #1}}%
        {{}^{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}%
    }%
}

%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
%  \markboth{\MakeTextUppercase{\ \ \ \ Essays in xx}}{}%
%}


\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}


            {\Large \textbf{Essays in xx}}\\ \vspace{2 cm}

            \large{Mr x}\\ \vspace{1.5 cm}


            {\normalsize \textsc{Dissertation}} \\
            {\normalsize \textsc{for obtaining the degree of}} \\
            {\normalsize \textsc{Doctor of Business and Economics}} \\
            {\normalsize \textsc{Doctor Rerum Politicarum (Dr. Rer. Pol.)}} \\ \vspace{2 cm}

            {\normalsize \textsc{xx}}\\ \vspace{1 cm}

            {\normalsize \textsc{xx}}\\ \vspace{1 cm}

            {\normalsize \textsc{May 2020}}\\ \vspace{1 cm}

            \vspace*{\fill}

            {\normalsize \textsc{Referee: Professor Dr.\ xx}}\\ 
            {\normalsize \textsc{Co-Referee: Professor Dr.\ xx}}\\ 

        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}


% Chapter 1: Introduction
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Section}

\clearpage

Some text here

\clearpage

Some more text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally \chapter goes on odd pages and section doesn't even start a new page.  Then again, I haven't gone through your entire peramble.  DIV12?  emptypage?  changepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MWE in the question loads `fancyhdr` but the question is tagged with `scrlayer-scrpage`. Note that it is not possible to use both packages.

Suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage` (do not load package `fancyhdr`):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\rehead{\MakeUppercase{Title of the book}}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Suggestion using `fancyhdr` (do not load package `scrlayer-scrpage`):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\MakeUppercase{Title of the book}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% remove head rule
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

To remove the full stop after the chapter number in the header, you can either redefine `\chaptermark` (after `\pagestyle{fancy}`!):

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{\markboth {\MakeUppercase{\ifnum
      \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne \@chapapp\ \thechapter\ \ \fi #1}}{}}
\makeatother
```

or patch `\chaptermark` (after `\pagestyle{fancy}`!):

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\chaptermark{. }{\ }{}{\PatchFailed}
```

**Additional remark**: you must clean up your preamble.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Last question: The font in my example looks differently, is there a way to use the same font? And to get rid of that line?

Comment: @MANGo92 See my updated answer.

Comment: @asdd Any chance of getting rid of the full stop after "Chapter 1" ?

Comment: @MANGo92 I would suggest to use the `scrlayer-scrpage` version: there is no full stop after the chapter number in the page header. But see my updated answer for the fancyhdr version.